# antlr grammar for triple quoted string

Tags: java, antlr, antlr4, graphql, graphql-java

I am trying to update an ANTLR grammar that follows the following spec

https://github.com/facebook/graphql/pull/327/files

In logical terms its defined as

```
StringValue ::
   - `"` StringCharacter* `"`
   - `"""` MultiLineStringCharacter* `"""`

StringCharacter ::
  - SourceCharacter but not `"` or \ or LineTerminator
  - \u EscapedUnicode
  - \ EscapedCharacter

MultiLineStringCharacter ::
  - SourceCharacter but not `"""` or `\"""`
  - `\"""`
```

(Not the above is logical - not ANTLR syntax)

I tried the follow in ANTRL 4 but it wont recognize more than 1 character inside a triple quoted string

```
string : triplequotedstring | StringValue ;

triplequotedstring: '"""' triplequotedstringpart?  '"""';

triplequotedstringpart : EscapedTripleQuote* | SourceCharacter*;

EscapedTripleQuote : '\\"""';

SourceCharacter :[\u0009\u000A\u000D\u0020-\uFFFF];

StringValue: '"' (~(["\\\n\r\u2028\u2029])|EscapedChar)* '"';
```

With these rules it will recognize '"""a"""' but as soon as I add more characters it fails

eg: '"""abc"""' wont parse and the IntelliJ plugin for ANTLR says

```
line 1:14 extraneous input 'abc' expecting {'"""', '\\"""', SourceCharacter}
```

How do I do triple quoted strings in ANTLR with '\"""' escaping?

Answer (score 1):

Some of your parer rules should really be lexer rules. And `SourceCharacter` should probably be a `fragment`.

Also, instead of `EscapedTripleQuote* | SourceCharacter*`, you probably want `( EscapedTripleQuote | SourceCharacter )*`. The first matches `aaa...` or `bbb...`, while you probably meant to match `aababbba...`

Try something like this instead:

```
string
 : Triplequotedstring 
 | StringValue 
 ;

Triplequotedstring
 : '"""' TriplequotedstringPart*? '"""'
 ;

StringValue
 : '"' ( ~["\\\n\r\u2028\u2029] | EscapedChar )* '"'
 ;

// Fragments never become a token of their own: they are only used inside other lexer rules
fragment TriplequotedstringPart : EscapedTripleQuote | SourceCharacter;
fragment EscapedTripleQuote : '\\"""';
fragment SourceCharacter :[\u0009\u000A\u000D\u0020-\uFFFF];
```

Comment: Thanks for this.  I took the above as is and it seems to be making the IDEA ANTLR plugin happy so I will try it out in the code and see how I go.

Comment: Hmm spoke a little too soon - its too greedy so input like

   { field(triple : """"triple

string""", triple2 : """another string""" ) }

is being combined as one long triple string.

Comment: Ahh needed the non greedy ? indicator on the fragment

Comment: fragment TripleQuotedStringPart : ( EscapedTripleQuote | SourceCharacter))+?;

Answer (score 0):

Triple quoted strings are often used to allow multi-line strings and unescaped characters inside a string.
Assuming that you are skipping spaces and linebreaks, parsing triple quotes can be quite tricky, because there are some corner cases like:

- Since triple quotes are multi-line, the parsing errors should be adapted to that. If you define triple quotes as part of the **lexer**, with line breaks, the line (and column) numbers will be wrong.
- In case of """"""" (one double quote surrounded by triple quotes) the parsed result should be a string literal with content: "

In order to cope with the above issues a grammar with modes can be used is:

Lexer:

```
START_TRIPLE_QUOTE: '"""' -> pushMode(INSIDE_TRIPLE_QUOTE);

mode INSIDE_TRIPLE_QUOTE;
TRIPLE_QUOTED_STRING_CONTENT : '"' '"'? ~["]  // Match one or two quotes followed by a non-quote
                             | ~["]           // Match any character that is not a quote
                             ;
TRIPLE_QUOTE_END_2: '"""""' -> popMode;
TRIPLE_QUOTE_END_1: '""""' -> popMode;
TRIPLE_QUOTE_END_0: '"""' -> popMode;
```

Parser:

```
triple_string_literal: START_TRIPLE_QUOTE (TRIPLE_QUOTED_STRING_CONTENT)*
                              (TRIPLE_QUOTE_END_2
                              | TRIPLE_QUOTE_END_1
                              | TRIPLE_QUOTE_END_0);
```

And in your Listener/Visitor:

```
TripleQuotedStringConst(ctx.getText().substring(3, ctx.getText().length() - 3))
```

As a **reference** here is an article that I wrote: https://medium.com/@alexzerntev/parsing-multi-line-triple-quoted-strings-with-antlr4-ceca41cdeadb